# How to make line chart out of wide data in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, dataformat

My data table StatePopOverTime currently looks like this:

`State       2015  2016  2017  2018 (<- Varnames)
1    Alabama 90154 87611 89638 89026
2     Alaska 42198 41308 40940 37621
3    Arizona 21110 20660 20616 20939
4   Arkansas 87421 84496 87874 89325
5 California 81735 80427 79267 80599
6   Colorado 86786 86793 85698 82927`

I want to use ggplot2 to make a chart with 6 line graphs of how the values change over the years 2015-2018. I know my data format isn't correct, but I don't know what is. What code should I run to fix my data table so I can use ggplot?

Answer (score 1):

You need to reshape your data first. I would recommend looking up concepts such as `tidy data`; specifically, the `tidyr` package is a good place to start. The following should work:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(State = structure(1:6, .Label = c("Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado"), class = "factor"),  X2015 = c(90154L, 42198L, 21110L, 87421L, 81735L, 86786L), X2016 = c(87611L, 41308L, 20660L, 84496L, 80427L, 86793L), X2017 = c(89638L, 40940L, 20616L, 87874L, 79267L, 85698L), X2018 = c(89026L, 37621L, 20939L, 89325L, 80599L, 82927L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

df %>%
  gather(year, value, -State) %>%
  mutate(year = str_remove(year, "X")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = value, color = State, group = State)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image: Plot]